# How can I parse rdf* files with python? does rdflib sopport rdf*?

Tags: python, rdf-star

does rdflib support rdf* now?
how can I parse rdf* files in python?
Thanks.

Joylix

Comment: I think rdf* is too new to have the desired tool support yet. Additionally – and unfortunately, symbolic AI (i.e. semantic technology) seems to have only comparatively sparse tool support in the Python world. See also https://github.com/cknoll/semantic-python-overview/discussions/1

If you meanwhile have found a (maybe indirect) way to load rdf* into Python, please share your knowledge.