# how to read th RDF-Turtle Star file with Python?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdflib, turtle-rdf, rdf-star

I have a .ttls file . i want to read it with python and extract some information. I googled a bit. there is the library rdflib. but I think it doesn't support the .ttls file. does anyone have any idea how i can read this .ttls file with python?

Comment: have you tried this repo: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-rdfstar ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicte of [How can I parse rdf* files with python? does rdflib sopport rdf*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65951549/how-can-i-parse-rdf-files-with-python-does-rdflib-sopport-rdf)
No answer

Python rdflib issue about this topic: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/issues/955

Have you tried this repo: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib-rdfstar ?
(I didn't!)

A robust indirect solution is to use a triple store (such as [GraphDB](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/)) load your rdf* data and query it through the [graphDB python API](https://pypi.org/project/graphdb-python/)
[Other implementations](https://w3c.github.io/rdf-star/implementations.html) declared by the [RDF-star working group](https://w3c.github.io/rdf-star/) are few other options.

Answer (score 0):

rdf-star (turtle) can be parsed by https://pyoxigraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/